# System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the registry key

Tags: iis, tfs

I have some code that calls the TFS API and returns team meta data. (e.g. team names, area paths, etc.)  The code works fine locally in Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC project, but fails whenever I deploy to the server.

**What I have tried that didn't work:**

I granted the AppPool user account Full control to the registry key (**did not work**)
Also, tried granting Everyone Full Control to the registry key (**still did not work**)
Any insight into how to set up the correct permissions of configuration for IIS deployed apps to hit the TFS API would be greatly appreciated. (**error message below**)

**Here's the Error message the app produces:**

System.UnauthorizedAccessException

```
Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio' is denied.

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.RegistryTokenStorageHelper.GetRootKey(String subkeyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.RegistryTokenStorage.RetrieveToken(VssTokenKey tokenKey)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentialStorage.RetrieveToken(Uri serverUrl, VssCredentialsType credentialType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.CookieCredential.OnCreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, HttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.IssuedTokenCredential.CreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, HttpWebResponse response, IssuedToken failedToken)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentials.TryGetTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, IssuedTokenProvider& provider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestHelpers.PrepareWebRequest(HttpWebRequest webRequest, Guid sessionId, String operationName, CultureInfo cultureInfo, TfsRequestSettings settings, TfsClientCredentials credentials, IdentityDescriptor impersonate, IssuedToken& currentToken, IssuedTokenProvider& tokenProvider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestHelpers.CreateSoapRequest(Uri requestUri, Guid sessionId, String soapAction, String operationName, CultureInfo cultureInfo, TfsRequestSettings settings, TfsClientCredentials credentials, IdentityDescriptor impersonate, IssuedToken& currentToken, IssuedTokenProvider& tokenProvider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.CreateWebRequest()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationProxy.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.RefreshMemoryCache()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.IRegistration.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.IdentityManagementService..ctor(TfsConnection tfsBase)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.IdentityManagementService2..ctor(TfsConnection tfsBase)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateInternalProxy(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService[T]()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamService.QueryTeams(String projectId)
```

Comment: Any chance IIS is configured to run ASP.NET in medium or lower trust? That denies access to the registry regardless of your actual permissions... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx

Comment: See: http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/How_do_I_create_a_custom_trust_level_for_ASP.NET%3F

Comment: That was an interesting idea.  But no, trust is not the problem.  I did a default install of IIS and Windows Server 2012.  Per docs: "By default, the trust level for application domains for ASP.NET is full trust. The partial-trust behavior in ASP.NET takes effect when the trustLevel element's name attribute is set to a value other than Full."  I also checked the web.config file in \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version], and it looks like the trust level is full.   Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you had any further luck with this Allan.  I'm also experiencing the same issue.  The server has an install of TFS2013 plus VS2013 and VS2012. I removed both versions of VS but the issue still remained.   Strangely I deployed the Web Service to my machine (not using IIS Express but creating a website in IIS) and it works fine...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have been having the same problem and have solved it by setting the "Load User Profile" in IIS application pool settings to **True**.

I don't know if this is some new dependency in TFS 2013 or whether IIS 8.5 has changed the default, but this fixes it for me.

Comment: Awesome Greg - thanks so much for posting this, it fixed the issue straight away for me!  I would be really interested to know why it fixes it though and how you identified that this would fix it.

Comment: So the issue is unauthorized access to a HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key.  In my case IIS is running as application pool identity and I think by default the User Profile is not loaded.  Therefore there is no "Current User".  If you set "Load User Profile" to true, then the profile is loaded and access to HKEY_CURRENT_USER is possible.  

As you can probably tell, I don't know the exact info, this is just what I am inferring.

Comment: Yep.  That worked for me too.  I'm marking this one as done.  


Details
-------
1.  I went over to this URL and grabbed the config settings.  
    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity.aspx

2.  I updated my IIS ApplicationHost.config and reset IIS.

3.  Code features relying and TFS API calls are now working as expected.

Comment: It worked for me even on IIS 10, windows server 2022 (y)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, but setting Load User Profile to TRUE didn't work for me.  What did eventually work was going into the registry and adding a "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices" key for the appropriate user(s).  Apparently the TFS assemblies get a little cranky when you try to use them on systems without Visual Studio installed on them.

Credit goes to whoever added this information to http://msdn.developer-works.com/article/12173562/After+upgrade+from+TFS+2010+to+TFS+2013+the+soap+notifications+stop+working.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and setting the "Load User Profile" in IIS application pool settings to **True** worked for us.  But then the same issue came back and we found setting "Load User Profile" in IIS application pool settings to **False** fixed the issue once again.  So it appears to me that it is the toggling of this setting that is fixing something rather than the actual value it is set to.  No matter what "Load User Profile" in IIS application pool is set to, I would try toggling it to the opposite value, refresh the application pool and see if that helps.  If anyone tracks down the root cause of this please share.