# Access TFS via its API using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, tfs, windows-authentication

All,

I am using the ASP.Net MVC 4 application.
I have enabled **Windows Authentication**.

Till now it is working fine.

Now I enhanced the application to connect to TFS via its API.
For this, I need to use the windows authentication credentials.

I have tried using

```
ICredentialsProvider credential = new UICredentialsProvider();
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, credential);
```

This works great in the development environment. But when I host the application in IIS 8.5, it is not working at all under "**Application Pool Identity**" and "**Network Service**" account.

I tried with Local System and specific user in identity of application pool, it is working.

But I need this to work based on the windows credential (Active directory).

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You need impersonation so that user's windows credentials will be used for TFS connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I provide the impersonation, it is just waiting for the website to load (kind of hang).

Comment: What version of TFS? If you're using TFS 2015 or later, it may be easier to get the data via the TFS REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your web application on the TFS App Tier and configuring its app pool to run as the same identity as the TFS web services, and enable ASP.NET impersonation. Check this case: [ASP.NET MVC3 Windows Authentication Pass Through to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945080/asp-net-mvc3-windows-authentication-pass-through-to-tfs)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this, but it asks for credentials 3 times continuously and throws error that "Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio' is denied."

Comment: Try to set the "Load User Profile" in IIS application pool settings to True. Check solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268498/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-registry-key

Answer (score 0):

You are  likely hitting a  Kerberos double hope issue.

You have two options to resolve it:

1. Host your mvc web app on the same server as tfs
2. Configure Active Directory to allow your servers identity to delegate the logged in user credentials to another service.

**#1 is easy but #2 will require a bunch of work for your Active Directory domain administrators.**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/810572

You will need:

1. At least one Service Principal Name (SPN) configured for your server's account (either a dedicated domain\svc_myaccout or  the domain\servername$ account for Network Service).
2. The account you use needs to be enabled to allow delegation in AD
3. The server that hosts your application needs to be enabled for delegation

This is not 101 and in my  experience, having done this a bunch in enterprise  and small business, that most Domain Administrators  don't know how  Kerberos delegation works, or how to configure it.

You will need to learn how and make explicit requests that they can action. Like "run 'setspn myapp.mydomain.com domain\myserviceaccount'".